# -ObjC linker flag causes duplicate symbol errors

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, compiler-errors, static-libraries

I am required to include the -ObjC flag in "Other Linker Flags" in Xcode to use a 3rd-party component. However, once I add this flag, I get a slew of errors that look like this:

```
    duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GAI.defaultTracker_ in:
        /MyApp/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAI.o)
        /MyApp/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAI.o)
    duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_GAI.dispatcher_ in:
        /MyApp/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAI.o)
        /MyApp/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAI.o)
...
    duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_GAIDispatcher in:
        /MyApp/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAIDispatcher.o)
        /MyApp/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAIDispatcher.o)
    duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GAIDispatcher in:
        /MyApp/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalytics.a(GAIDispatcher.o)
        /MyApp/GoogleAnalytics/libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a(GAIDispatcher.o)
    ld: 212 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7s
```

Again, this all disappears if I don't use the -ObjC flag. It appears to have something to do with the Google Analytics library. How do I get around this?

Comment: seems like you've included _both_ the debug and normal version of the google analytics library

Comment: True, but the debug library is needed for debugging obviously. I don't get these errors when I don't use the -ObjC flag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit the release and debug configurations of your build target.  Include the debug version of the library in the debug config, and the non-debug version for the release target.  Don't include both in the same config--this is why you're getting duplicate symbols.

Remove the two libraries from your build targets, eg:

[image: remove libraries from build targets]

Then search for "other linker flags" in your build target's settings and add "-lGoogleAnalytics_debug" for the Debug config and "-lGoogleAnalytics" for the Release config, eg:

[image: set linker flags for debug and release configs]

Comment: How can I set libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a to only be included in the debug config?

Comment: I think there's a build setting to control library variants... (but might only work for dynamically loaded libraries)

Comment: You could try removing the library from your library build phase, then use the "Other Linker Flags" (__OTHER_LDFLAGS__) setting to link against the proper __libGoogleAnalytics__

Comment: Ha! I just finished suggesting that. Anyway, I already +1d you.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed edit. Works now. One question though - why "-lGoogleAnalytics_debug" instead of "-libGoogleAnalytics_debug"

Comment: The linker assumes that the library begins with "lib" (and ends with the ".a" extension) when you use the -l flag.